# Using common type interafaces for dependency injection(IoC), ninject, MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, repository, ninject

I have a problem. At first time when i introduce dependency injection(IoC) via IRepository pattern everything was ok. At that time i used for each repository individual interface. Now i try to incorporate all interface's into one common type interface and now i get trouble with ninject controller factrory. "Exception while casting" in GetControllerInstance method

```
public interface IRepositoryEF<TAble> where TAble: class
{
    IQueryable<TAble> GetAll();

    void Add(TAble);

    TAble GetById(long id);

    TAble DeleteById(long id);
}
public interface MealsRepositoryEF: IRepositoryEF<Meal>
{
     IQueryable<Meal> GetAllAsQueryable()
     {
     }
     void Add(Meal meal)
     {
     }
     Meal GetById(long id)
     {
     }
     Meal DeleteById(long id)
     {
     }
}
public interface GoalsRepositoryEF: IRepositoryEF<Goal>
{
    IQueryable<Goal> GetAllAsQueryable()
    {
    }
    void Add(Goal goal)
    {
    }
    Patient GetById(long id)
    {
    }
    Patient DeleteById(long id)
    {
    }
}



public class NinjectControllerFactory: DefaultControllerFactory {
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory() {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, 
        Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null? 
            null :
            (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);         
    }

    private void AddBindings() {
        // put additional bindings here
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepositoryEF<Meal>>().To(typeof(MealsRepositoryEF));
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepositoryEF<Goal>>().To(typeof(GoalsRepositoryEF));
    }
}
public class MealsController : Controller
{
    private  IRepositoryEF<Meal> mealsRepository;

    public PatientController(IRepositoryEF<Meal> repo)
    {
        mealsRepository= repo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also while i use dependency injection of common type interface via console application all works great.

Comment: Please post the exact exception message, type, and stack trace.